# server side progress status on frontend

Tags: angular, server, request, backend

I'm trying to implement a functionality to an angular 2 app that gives status of how much data has been processed on the backend. So, basically, I'm sending the whole payload at the beginning and then server is doing some processing and once done, it's sending a response back which then I'm reflecting to the user that certain processing has successfully been done or not.

But, now, I want to have a way to also show the progress status to the user so that s/he knows how much percent has been done and how much to wait more.

What are the best practices to achieve this functionality? Do I need to send a GET request, say, every 5 sec to check the status? If yes, that might bring an interrupted UX. May be there are better elegant ways to achieve it. Feel free to improve the Q.